# whenever gem development environment rails not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, rake, whenever

I have a Rails application and want to perform a cron job(every 5 mins in development) via the whenever gem...

I have a rake task in: `lib/tasks/appname.rake`

code inside is:

```
namespace :appname do
  desc "Importing data overnight"
  task import_data_overnight: :environment do
    puts "importing..."
    Object.import_data
  end
end
```

When in terminal I run:

```
$bundle exec rake appname:import_data_overnight
```

My development database gets updated perfectly.

Adding in the whenever gem this is what I put in:

Gemfile: `gem 'whenever', require: false`

cd into my project

ran: `$wheneverize .`

inside `config/schedule.rb`:

```
set :environment, :development
set :output, {:error => "log/cron.log", :standard => "log/cron.log"}

every 5.minutes do
  rake "appname:import_data_overnight"
end
```

Save the file, then inside terminal I ran:

```
$whenever --update-crontab --set environment=development
```

This is the output in my `cron.log`:

```
Jun  4 13:05:00 Jatins-MacBook-Pro.local /usr/sbin/cron[34183]: (jatin) CMD (/bin/bash -l -c 'cd /Users/jatin/dev/apps/appname && RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake appname:import_data_overnight --silent >> log/cron_log.log 2>> log/cron_error_log.log')
```

Looks like its running, but when I check my db there is no sign of any activity, no records are touched.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the output of your `log/cron_error_log.log`

Comment: There is actually no file like that. So i changed `:error` and `:standard` both to `log/cron.log` ... the output is exactly the same as above .... there is no error

Comment: Why is the app name different when you are running from terminal and when you are running from cron job?

Comment: I replaced the application name to appname for this post. I just forgot to change it. Everything is consist in my application. I just updated the post.

Comment: Can you run `crontab -l` and post the result in the question?

Comment: `# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: /Users/jatin/dev/apps/appname/config/schedule.rb
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /Users/jatin/dev/apps/appname && RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake appname:import_data_overnight --silent >> log/cron.log 2>> log/cron.log'

# End Whenever generated tasks for: /Users/jatinbhandari/dev/apps/appname/config/schedule.rb`